# Average number of iterations for the Euclidean algorithm to terminate

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, continued-fractions

Let $N$ be a positive integer and $0 \leq s < N$.
We try to divide $s$ into $N$ using the Euclidean algorithm:

$N = q_1 s + r_1 $

$r = q_2 r_1 + r_2 $

$\vdots$

$r_{K-1} = q_{K-1} r_K$

If we choose $-r_{i-1}/2 \leq r_i < r_{i-1}/2$, I think this determines the $q_i$'s uniquely, but I don't think this matters for my question.

For a fixed $N$ and $0 \leq s < N$, define $K_s$ to be the number of iterations before the Euclidean algorithm terminates, (i.e. $K$ in the instance written above).

Are there existing tools to characterize
$$ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{0 \leq s < N} K_s, $$
for a given $N$?

Comment: I think this is discussed in detail in Knuth, Seminumerical Algorithms.

Comment: Here https://sci-hub.se/https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/SM8718/meta you can find a rather precise answer if you're interested in $s$ comprime to $N$. Perhaps not surprisingly the answer is of order $O(\log{N})$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This algorithm correspons to [nearest integer continued fractions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NearestIntegerContinuedFraction.html) or centered continued fraction. The length of such fraction $l(a/b)$ can be expressed in terms of Gauss - Kuz'min statistics for classical continued fraction expansion, see [The mean number of steps in the Euclidean algorithm with least absolute value remainders](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134%2FS0001434609010179). It means that all results known for for classical continued fractions can be applied in this case as well. In particular average length is known to be
$$\dfrac{1}{\varphi(b)}\sum\limits_{1\le a\le b\atop(a,b)=1}l(a/b)=
\dfrac{2\log \varphi}{\zeta(2)}\cdot\log
b+C+O_{\varepsilon}(b^{-1/6+\varepsilon}).$$

For the recent adnances see [The average length of finite continued fractions with fixed denominator](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=8718&option_lang=eng) by Bykovskii and Frolenkov.

Comment: These are really interesting results! I'm a bit embarrassed to not notice the connection to continued fractions.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I imagine it would not be difficult to get estimates for $\sum_{1\leq a<b} l(a/b)$ and not just for $(a,b)=1$.

Comment: @soupy Yes, you need to apply Mobius inversion formula. But result will be not so nice-looking, see Knuth, Seminumerical Algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

The complexity analysis of the Euclidean algorithm is much much older that the given reference. It goes back to at least Lamé, before 1785. The [above answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/342156) should be viewed as modern version of Lamé's theorem. The average is actually a normal variable, there are several difficult proofs, see [Morris - A short proof that the number of division steps in the Euclidean algorithm is normally distributed](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.07616), and earlier references.

Comment: By "the given reference", do you mean the reference*s* given in @AlexeyUstinov's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/342156)?  (Also, surely you mean that the *number of steps* is a normal variable, rather than that the *average* is a normal variable?)